# How to upload a file to eclipse workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I am writing a spring application, it has a functionality to upload file, I know how to upload file to h drive, but not sure how to do it on the current workspace.

Here is my servlet that takes control of file uploading:

```
@RequestMapping(value="UploadServlet", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void uploadfile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
    filePath = "/resources/images/";
     System.out.println(filePath);
    isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      java.io.PrintWriter out = response.getWriter( );
      if( !isMultipart ){
         out.println("<html>");
         out.println("<head>");
         out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");  
         out.println("</head>");
         out.println("<body>");
         out.println("<p>No file uploaded</p>"); 
         out.println("</body>");
         out.println("</html>");
         return;
      }
      DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
      // maximum size that will be stored in memory
      factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);
      // Location to save data that is larger than maxMemSize.
      factory.setRepository(new File("c:\\temp"));

      // Create a new file upload handler
      ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
      // maximum file size to be uploaded.
      upload.setSizeMax( maxFileSize );

      try{ 
      // Parse the request to get file items.
      List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

      // Process the uploaded file items
      Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();

      out.println("<html>");
      out.println("<head>");
      out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");  
      out.println("</head>");
      out.println("<body>");
      while ( i.hasNext () ) 
      {
         FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();
         if ( !fi.isFormField () )  
         {
            // Get the uploaded file parameters
            String fileName = fi.getName();

            // Write the file
            if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ){
               file = new File( filePath + 
               fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;
            }else{
               file = new File( filePath + 
               fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
            }
            System.out.println("Printing that thing");
            System.out.println(filePath + 
               fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1));
            System.out.println(fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1));

            fi.write( file ) ;

         }
      }

   }catch(Exception ex) {
       System.out.println(ex);
   }
    }
}
```

I know the problem is with the file path variable,

```
filePath = "/resources/images/";
```

I want the file to be written to Deployed Resources --> webapp --> resources --> images

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String)) to translate a a relative resource into a real file system path.

```
String filePath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/resources/images/");
```

Note that, at the end of the day, this as little to do with Eclipse and the way it managers servers and deployment. In fact, Eclipse may get in the way and cause problems you will not have in a standalone web server. For example, when Eclipse detects changes in the project it redeploys the files and may overwrite anything you changed or uploaded.